# How to change the iFrame src on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, web

```
 <section class="ep1">
        <iframe src="https://example.com" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
 </section>
<button onclick="setURL(`https://example.com/new`)"> Episode 2 </button>
```

```
 <script>
        function setURL(url) {
            document.getElementById('iframe').src = "url";
        }
 </script>
```

This code won't work on clicking the button.

I tried the given code, I am expecting that onclicking the button src of the iframe should change.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById('iframe') will look for an element with ID="iframe". The given iframe does not have an ID.

try:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://example.com" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

or:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you are selecting an element with an `id` of `iframe`. your element does not have an `id`. This should work (this is selecting an element with the `iframe` tag):

```html
     <script>
            function setURL(url) {
                document.querySelector('iframe').src = "https://website.com";
            }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('iframe').src = "url";`

You should remove the quotations around url and also give the iframe a id.
So it should look like this

`document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;`